# Why is my image adding a lot of white space

Tags: html, css

Whenever I used the picture of myself image, it adds a lot of white space to the bottom of the page. I do not know why. Whenever the image is removed, the white space is gone.

I have tried to play with the margin and padding. I kept searching for answers on the internet and couldn't find anything. I tried to get rid of the overflow but it does not seem like it does anything. Please give me any solutions you can.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
* {
  padding: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 200px 1fr 3em;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "nav " " banner" " main" " footer";
}

header {
  grid-area: banner;
}

header img {
  grid-area: banner;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

header h1 {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #FFFCFC;
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #232770;
  top: 0;
  flex-direction: row;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

nav ul li {
  margin: 3px 40px;
}

nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #C2C4F0;
}

nav li a:hover {
  color: #FFFCFC;
}

body {
  background-color: #ECECEC;
  width: 100%;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: #232770;
  color: #C2C4F0;
  text-align: center;
}


/* for when there isn't enough content to put the footer on the bottom */

#footerfix {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
}

main p {
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-family: ;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#landing {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

main img {
  border-radius: 100px;
  height: 10%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

h2 {
  font-family: ;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Exercises</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <header>
    <h1>Max's Advanced Webscripting Page</h1>
    <img src="img/header.jpeg" alt="" rel="preload">
  </header>

  <main>
    <img src="img/self.JPG" alt="Picture of Max">
    <p id="landing">My name is Max and I am a web developer. I am 21 years old and currently in college for web developement. I will be showcasing JavaScript and JQuery work I have done throughout the semester. I will also be showcasing other skills I have learned from
      other langauges (like HTML and CSS) and how to make them all work together.</p>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <p>&copy; Max Reitmayer 2024</p>
  </footer>

</div>
```

Comment: How about setting an absolute height to the main img? e.g. something like height: 100px?

Comment: You helped fixed it. I didn't think percentages would affect it like that.

Comment: The space that you see comes from the absolute image height. It's all about how the fr unit gets calculated in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're using Grid.

```
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: 50px 200px 1fr 3em;
grid-template-columns: 1fr;
grid-template-areas:
  "nav"
  "banner"
  "main"
  "footer";
```

Image part is banner part. So height is 200px. Also you are using position absolute. That's why its happening like this.

But if you want 100%, you can do like this.

```
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */
* {
  padding: 0;

}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 200px 1fr 3em;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "nav"
    "banner"
    "main"
    "footer";
}

header {
  grid-area: banner;
  position: relative;
}

header img {
  grid-area: banner;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

header h1 {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #FFFCFC;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

}


nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #232770;
  top: 0;
  flex-direction: row;

}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;


}

nav ul li {
  margin: 3px 40px;


}

nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #C2C4F0;
}

nav li a:hover {
  color: #FFFCFC;
}

body {
  background-color: #ECECEC;
  width: 100%;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: #232770;
  color: #C2C4F0;
  text-align: center;
}

/* for when there isn't enough content to put the footer on the bottom */
#footerfix {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
}

main p {
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-family: ;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

}

#landing {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;

}

main img {
  border-radius: 100px;
  height: 10%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

}

h2 {
  font-family: ;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
}
```